# How to view all current uncommmited changes to a specific file in hg?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

How to look at all uncommited changes to a file in hg? If we use TortoiseHG it's clear, but what about command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want some combination of

`hg status -mad` to list all Modified, Added and Deleted files,

and `hg diff <filename>` to show the changes in a particular file.